# OpenCV HoughCircles occasionally returning [0. 0. 0.]

Tags: python, opencv

I'm running `HoughCircles()` on an HSV filtered PiCamera feed on a Raspberry Pi to detect a pink ball. Occasionally I will get a ndarray result of `[[[0. 0. 0.]]]` which is the same as `np.zeros(shape=(1, 1, 3))`, rather than the expected `None` when there is no round shape in the camera's view. I looked at the docs but didn't see any details on why it would return this. I also looked at the source but can't find the Python wrapper for the [C++ code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp), which doesn't seem to help me either.

Here's my function call:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(frame, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 3, frame.shape[0] / 4, param1=220, param2=110, minRadius=5)
```

I'm wondering why if it's doing something like identifying something incredibly small that I can't even see on the `imshow()` (which is always completely black around (0,0); dozens of rows and columns of nothing but zeros), then why is it always at (0,0) with a radius of 0? I don't see how it would return the circle with a radius of 0 when I supplied `minRadius=5`. I don't believe this is actually a valid detection. Sometimes it takes hundreds of executions for this to happen but it seems that I can trigger it by moving something by the camera quickly such as my hand.

Any ideas why this is happening, maybe somebody else has experienced this?

Comment: I recently found that, after updating some python packages including opencv, the HoughCircles function started returning `(0,0,0)` instead of `None` when no circles were detected. I have not found any reason or documentation for this, and the solution has been to handle this return value explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, @Mick, it's odd that I'm getting both then. I'm using 3.4.3; which version did you update to?

Comment: I currently have opencv-python 3.4.3.18 installed.

Comment: "but can't find the Python wrapper" -- the implementation of all the wrappers is generated automatically during a build. Build OpenCV with Python support, and then search for `pyopencv_*.h`.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Windows -- the standard 3.4.3 build still returns `None` (just calling it on a completely black input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into an identical issue in C++ where HoughCircles() would return a list with a single [0,0,0] in it for certain images. This was found to be caused by a bug in the RemoveOverlaps() method in OpenCV and will be fixed in future releases (e.g. 3.4.7, 4.2.0, etc).

If you want more info, take a look at the bug report that I wrote:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14432

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as the correct answer since it seems to be a viable root cause.